# Why is my hamburger menu closing when I first open the page?

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, hamburger-menu

Any help is appreciated and thanks.

The problem:

Basically when you first open the web page (and only the first time, or when you refresh the web page) you see the hamburger menu closing, I do not want this, I only want the hamburger menu to open once you click on it and close once you click on it again.

Here's the problem shown on a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRYnvGgtqd0
(The problem occurs when I refresh the page)

I have inserted the code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "Calibri", Arial;
}

section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    position: relative;
    animation: change 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}

h1{
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 5rem 10rem;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
}

@keyframes change {
    0%{
    background-position: 0 50%;
    }
    50%{
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100%{
    background-position: 0 50%;
    }
}

.menu-wrap{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

 .menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .menu-wrap .hamburger > div:before,
 .menu-wrap .hamburger > div:after {

    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: inherit;    
 }

 .menu-wrap .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 10px;
 }

 .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
 }

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div{
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
    visibility: visible;

}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition-duration: 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.menu-wrap .menu > div {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200vw;
    height: 200vw;
    display: flex;
    flex: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 90vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li > a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.4s ease;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pranav's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
        <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Assignment 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Assignment 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Assignment 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section> 
        <h1 class="animatedText">Hello, I'm Pranav</h1>
    </section>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem that you show in the youtube video doesn't occur with the code that you pasted here. I ran the code snippet and everything is normal (no menu closing at page load) and same thing when I run your code in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I sort of fixed the problem.

I removed the 'transition: all 0.4s ease;' in

.menu-wrap .menu > div {

background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);

border-radius: 50%;

width: 200vw;

height: 200vw;

display: flex;

flex: none;

align-items: center;

justify-content: center;

transform: scale(0);

transition: all 0.4s ease;

}

And now the problem isn't there! However, now the transition when you click on the menu is not there.

Answer (score 1):

1). If you want your menu first-time show close then flow below code

```
 <input type="checkbox"   class="toggler">
```

2).and you first-time want to open then flow below code

```
<input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" class="toggler">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as far as I can the, the thread owner's question is not how to open or close the hamburger menu but how to remove that unwanted effect on page load.